# Weird MySQL CURDATE() behaviour (maybe affected by CAST?)

Tags: mysql, datetime

I wanted to know the number of users being created every day, grouped by the date, for the last 5 / 10 / 15 days.

Here is the query I used for the datewise signups for the last 5 days:

```
SELECT CAST(created AS DATE) as DateField , count(email) as Num 
FROM invited_users where created > curdate()-5 
GROUP BY CAST(created AS DATE);

// "created" is a datetime field
// returns 5 rows
```

This works just as I expected it to.

But, when I change the number "5" to "10" or 15 (or anything other than 5, it seems to me), it doesn't work! Instead, it returns ALL the dates in the database!

```
SELECT CAST(created AS DATE) as DateField , count(email) as Num 
FROM invited_users where created > curdate()-15 
GROUP BY CAST(created AS DATE);

// returns 97 rows
```

Why?! What is going on here?

Btw, the same happens with any other table too.

EDIT:

```
select curdate(), curdate() -5, curdate() - 15, curdate() + 1, curdate() + 0;
```

gives the following result:
    3/5/2013 12:00:00 AM    20130300    20130290    20130306    20130305

I did not understand how this is being calculated. While CURDATE()+1 gives tomorrows date, CURDATE() - 5 gives me a value I cannot decode.

Comment: MySQL does not support this kind of date arithmetic. You will need to use `date_add()` (or `date_sub()`)  for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```